# Are there as many hair follicles in your nose as on your head?

Tags: biology

The [Cleveland Clinic website on nose hair](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/nose-hair-safari-infographic) says, "The inner surface of your nose has as many hair follicles as your head.". That seems like a lot!

From a few measurements (sample size N=1 lmao), I think I can model my head as a sphere of radius at least 10cm, with at least 1/3rd covered with hair, and each nostril as a cylinder of length at most 4cm and radius at most 0.7cm. With that model, I get at least 630cm<sup>2</sup> available for hair on my head, and at most 35cm<sup>2</sup> available for hair in my nose, a ratio of about 18:1. The hair in my nose certainly doesn't *look* 20× as dense as the hair on my head!

From a search online, heads typically have ~100k hair follicles. I've searched for a similar stat for noses, but come up short; the closest I got is a claim that each nose hair follicle grows 200cm of hair in a typical lifetime, but there's no obvious (to me) calculation from that fact to follicle count.

I know the hair in my nose is unsightly, but is it really that dense?

Comment: The statement they make is a bit ambiguous; I think it's just as likely that they mean that the density is the same/similar on the head and inside the nose, rather than the sum count.

Comment: Perhaps they included cilia in the nose population.